# FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. * What went wrong: // Execution failed for task ':app:mergeExtDexDebug',

Tags: flutter, dart

When try to run the flutter dart program on physical device mobile at that time below error will show sometimes in Android Studio terminal :

Note: C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\cloud_firestore-4.14.0\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\firestore\FlutterFirebaseFirestorePlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
ERROR:D8: Cannot fit requested classes in a single dex file (# methods: 112826 > 65536)
com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives:
The number of method references in a .dex file cannot exceed 64K.
Learn how to resolve this issue at https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:mergeExtDexDebug'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.DexMergingTaskDelegate
> There was a failure while executing work items
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.DexMergingWorkAction
> com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives:
> The number of method references in a .dex file cannot exceed 64K.
> Learn how to resolve this issue at https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 4m 1s
[!] App requires Multidex support
Multidex support is required for your android app to build since the number of methods has exceeded 64k. See https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#enabling-multidex-support for more information. You may pass the --no-multidex flag to skip Flutter's multidex support to use a manual solution.

Flutter tool can add multidex support. The following file will be added by flutter:

android/app/src/main/java/io/flutter/app/FlutterMultiDexApplication.java

cannot prompt without a terminal ui
Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

When the above Error show in the Android Studio Terminal at that time we should set minSdkVersion 21.
There are two build.gradle files in Android Studio.

1st build.gradle file : 1st build.gradle file is located at android folder -> build.gradle.

2nd build.gradle file : 2nd build.gradle file is located at android folder -> app folder -> build.gradle.

We have to select 2nd option from above shown options.
In the app level build.gradle file, we have to set android { defaultConfig { minSdkVersion 21 } }.
we have to set minSdkVersion 21 as shown above.

After doing this, above Android Studio console problem will be solved.

Answer (score 0):

When the above Error show in the Android Studio Terminal at that time we should set minSdkVersion 21. There are two build.gradle files in Android Studio.

1st build.gradle file : 1st build.gradle file is located at android folder -> build.gradle.

2nd build.gradle file : 2nd build.gradle file is located at android folder -> app folder -> build.gradle.

We have to select 2nd option from above shown options. In the app level build.gradle file, we have to set android { defaultConfig { minSdkVersion 21 } }. we have to set minSdkVersion 21 as shown above.

After doing this, above Android Studio console problem will be solved.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Simply put you should enable multidex in your app level build.gradle

```
android {
defaultConfig {
    ...
    minSdk = 15 
    targetSdk = 33
    multiDexEnabled = true
}
...
```

}

https://developer.android.com/build/multidex

Answer (score -1):

```
android {
  defaultConfig
  {
    minSdkVersion 21
  }
}
```